# PHP calling several functions at once?

Tags: php, host

I am new to php and trying to run three functions in parallel. I have a code similar to the following:

```
Call function1(…….);  //all these function are located in separate host server
Call function2(…….);  
Call function3(…….);
```

All the above functions will be running for 5 min or more. Therefore, I really need to call them in parallel, if not my program will run for 15 min or more. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: PHP is not a threaded/parallellizable language. Run 3 separate PHP scripts, each calling one of those functions.

Comment: Similar
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684290/executing-functions-in-parallel
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998314/executing-functions-parallelly-in-php

Comment: Without knowing what exactly are 'functions' in your example, it's hard to recommend anything. In some cases you may need to look for something like [Gearman](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gearman.php), in some there might be already some 'pooling' technique implemented in your particular tools of trade.

Comment: There are just too many duplicates for this question. Research first, ask later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pThread` , here is a good place to start :

- [How can one use multi threading in PHP applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70855/how-can-one-use-multi-threading-in-php-applications/15501449#15501449)
- [Improving HTML scraper efficiency with pcntl_fork()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861969/improving-html-scraper-efficiency-with-pcntl-fork/15691424#15691424)
- [How do you make good use of multicore CPUs in your PHP/MySQL applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267345/how-do-you-make-good-use-of-multicore-cpus-in-your-php-mysql-applications/16822126#16822126)
- [pcntl runs the same code several times, assistance required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16383803/pcntl-runs-the-same-code-several-times-assistance-required/16431346#16431346)
- [Calling rand/mt_rand on forked children yields identical results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14879151/calling-rand-mt-rand-on-forked-children-yields-identical-results/14879531#14879531)

Example

```
$ts = array();
$ts[] = new Call("function1");
$ts[] = new Call("function2");
$ts[] = new Call("function3");

foreach($ts as $t) {
    $t->start();
}

foreach($ts as $t) {
    $t->join();
}
```

Simple Thread Class

```
class Call extends Thread {

    function __construct($func) {
        $this->func = $func;
    }

    function run() {
        call_user_func($this->func);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: [pThread is experimental](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pthreads.php#usernotes).

Comment: Using it in production for a while now ....

Comment: @Baba Thank you so much for explaning this to me in detail. I was trying to install pthread in my computer and my php code keep saying `Fatal error: Class 'Thread' not found`. can you please tell me what should I install to run this pthread. I would greatly apriciate your help