# Alternatives to using PHP to fetch and parse large number of remote XMLs?

Tags: php, xml

I need to make a large number of queries to a remote API through PHP. The request and response are both in XML. The XML by itself is not large but the number of requests is huge (approx. 5000).

PHP is simply taking too long for the whole process.

Any solution or suggestions for this?

I was thinking of maybe breaking up the process so that I can use a software (something like wget) to fetch the XMLs and saving them on harddisk and then PHP can just got and parse the XMLs. Not sure if this is going to be any faster.

Are there any automated tools available which I can use to fetch and parse remote XMLs and then maybe trigger a task.

Will this process be faster if I code it in say Python or Java?

Comment: Unless the parsing is quite involved the bottleneck is going to be from the requests. In that case using a faster language like java isn't going to give you any real speed improvements.

Comment: I dont think that i would run faster in any other language. Better try to parallelize. http://php.net/manual/de/function.pcntl-fork.php http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998314/executing-functions-parallelly-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind the bottleneck may very well not be PHP (most definitely not IMO). Are you running your Curl calls serially (one at a time)? There are tools available to make multiple curl calls at once through multiple processes (pcntl_fork and curl_multi_exec). Keep in mind how many calls you can make at one time to this service though.

If your application requires some communication or shared memory between these calls, then you may want to look into another language (GoLang is super equipped for these types of tasks)

Comment: Thanks for suggesting curl_multi_exec